# Update body content and header meta tags content in PHP page without database Connectivity

Tags: php, jquery, html, wordpress

I created a website for a client of my company. I tried to add a new option like whatever may be the content like title, meta tags, description, body tag, paragraph tag the user can change directly in admin panel so that content will be modified in corresponding page. For that I have one admin panel where the user select page name means it will retrieve content all tags text in corresponding text boxes and if the user changes anything and submit content will directly update in particular page. For this I retrieve page content with following code

```
<div class="form-group">
          <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="pwd">Meta Keyword</label>
          <div class="col-sm-10">
            <textarea class="form-control" id="meta_keyword"><?php echo $tags['keywords']; ?></textarea>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="pwd">Meta Description</label>
          <div class="col-sm-10">
            <textarea class="form-control" id="meta_desc"><?php echo $tags['description']; ?></textarea>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="pwd">Title</label>
          <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="title" value="<?php echo get_title($_GET['id']); ?>">
          </div>
        </div>

     <?php
    include_once('simple_html_dom.php');
    function get_title($url){
      $str = file_get_contents($url);
      if(strlen($str)>0){
        $str = trim(preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $str)); // supports line breaks inside <title>
        preg_match("/\<title\>(.*)\<\/title\>/i",$str,$title); // ignore case
        return $title[1];
      }
    }
    ?>
```

Is there any way to update the changed content directly in PHP page? But the dynamic change will not take place from database. Please anyone help me to get out of this problem. I tried in many ways but it is not working properly.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you want the changes to be live, you will have to use AJAX. PHP is a server side language and is therefore unable to make changes to a page that is already sent to the client.

Comment: Its not for single page.website may have multiple page admin should have authority to change content in any page

Comment: But can i do with ajax Is that whats the way to do